# SQL select bottom half

Tags: sql, select

I want to select second half of records of my table. What I came up with is that:

```
select top 50 percent column1, column2 from
(
select top (select count(*) from myTable) column1, column2 from myTable
order by column1 desc
) s 
order by column1
```

If I execute all but last line, it does work - it shows top half of records in a descend order, so what I need is to change again their order. Unfortunately, executing the last line makes the result totally different, i.e. top half taken right from original table.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: actually column1 consists of set of increasing numbers, so it makes kind of ordering in this case. But in general, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the 50% in the inner query:

```
select * from
(
select top 50 percent column1, column2 from myTable
order by column1 desc
) s 
order by column1 asc
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!